# C# persistent cookie

Tags: c#, razor, cookies

I have seen the persistent cookies examples in ASP.NET MVC C# here on stackoverflow.
But I can't figure out why the code below isn't working.

First I write to the cookie:

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("AdminPrintModule");
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(36);

cookie.Values.Add("PrinterSetting1", Request.QueryString["Printer1"]);
cookie.Values.Add("PrinterSetting2", Request.QueryString["Printer2"]);
cookie.Values.Add("PrinterSetting3", Request.QueryString["Printer3"]);

Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

I see the cookies stored in Internet Explorer. The content looks OK.

Then the reading code:

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["AdminPrintModule"];
test = cookie.Values["PrinterSetting2"].ToString();
```

The cookie variable keeps null . Storing the PrinterSetting2 value in the test variable fails.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong because this is more or less a copy-paste from the examples here on stackoverflow. Why can't I read the PrinterSetting2 value from the cookie ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with below code :-

```
if (Request.Cookies["AdminPrintModule"] != null)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["AdminPrintModule"];
    test = cookie["PrinterSetting2"].ToString();
}
```

Have a look at this document http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/annathurai/cookies-in-Asp-Net/ :-

Below are few types to write and read cookies :-

> Non-Persist Cookie - A cookie has expired time Which is called as
>   Non-Persist Cookie
>
> How to create a cookie?     Its really easy to create a cookie in the
>   Asp.Net with help of Response object or HttpCookie
>
> > Example 1:
> >
> > ```
> >     HttpCookie userInfo = new HttpCookie("userInfo");
> >     userInfo["UserName"] = "Annathurai";
> >     userInfo["UserColor"] = "Black";
> >     userInfo.Expires.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
> >     Response.Cookies.Add(userInfo);
> > ```
> >
> > Example 2:
> >
> > ```
> >     Response.Cookies["userName"].Value = "Annathurai";
> >     Response.Cookies["userColor"].Value = "Black";
> > ```
> >
> > **How to retrieve from cookie?**
> >
> > Its easy way to retrieve cookie value form cookes by help of Request
> >     object.     Example 1:
> >
> > ```
> >     string User_Name = string.Empty;
> >     string User_Color = string.Empty;
> >     User_Name = Request.Cookies["userName"].Value;
> >     User_Color = Request.Cookies["userColor"].Value;
> > ```
> >
> > Example 2:
> >
> > ```
> >     string User_name = string.Empty;
> >     string User_color = string.Empty;
> >     HttpCookie reqCookies = Request.Cookies["userInfo"];
> >     if (reqCookies != null)
> >     {
> >         User_name = reqCookies["UserName"].ToString();
> >         User_color = reqCookies["UserColor"].ToString();
> >     }
> > ```

Comment: I understand this prevent the failure, but it doesn't solve my problem with reading the PrinterSetting2 value from the cookie. Why can't I read this value ?

Comment: instead of putting value[""] try as I have done in my example @Walt501

Comment: I copy-paste your example 1 , but breakpoints before exiting the function and checked the values. Writing the cookie goes well, I can see all the values in the debug mode. Reading still deliveres a null value, I can also see that in the debug mode. I'm going nuts over here!

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that you have values in Request.QueryString.Just to check if your code works hard code values of cookies and then read from cookie.

Comment: I can check the content of the cookie with notepad. The values are stored as expected. But I can't seem to read them.

Comment: I have copied your code and it is working fine i can read value from cookie.